# построение графика валюты за выбранный период

Tags: python

Задача состоит в том чтобы построить график валюты "Чешская крона" за выбранный человеком период с графическим интерфейсом. Не могу понять как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Я бы попробовал библиотеку matplotlib:<https://pythonworld.ru/novosti-mira-python/scientific-graphics-in-python.html> Но не работал сам.

Comment: я работал с ней, знаю как строить. Но мне даны промежутки дат, который будет вводить человек. Тут-то я и встал.

Comment: Удивлюсь, если передача этих данных в неё невозможна. Но не буду утверждать, раз сам не работал.

Comment: даа... тяжела судьба, решить уже второй день не могу.:(

Comment: Вот, простые примеры для `pyplot.plot` c передачей параметров в библиотеку: <https://nsu-programming.github.io/textbook/python/plotting.html> В чем различие с ними?

Comment: Кароче я так понял нужно спарсить валюту допустим с  CBR, за промежуток который введет пользователь. Допустим с 2018 по 2020 год. и сделать график изменения по месяцам.

Comment: Это вопрос, или сообщение, что теперь примерно ясно, как делать? :-)

Comment: Ну идея как сделать есть, а то как выполнить это в коде нет(

Comment: Вы не описываете конкретную проблему.  Включил возможный подход к решению вашей задачи в ответ. Чем он не подходит?

Comment: Все подходит, по факту. Просто я тупенький

Comment: Не, не. для этого мозги почти не нужны. Я тупо вбивал в google запросы типа "примеры построения графиков в Python", "графики в Python с `plt.plot`" (когда увидел, что про него пишут) и получил быстро пример ниже. Уверен на 95%, что с ним ваша задача решается достаточно просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь запрашиваются данные с pandas-datareader. В данном случае чешская крона к доллару. Создается датафрейм pandas, взята дата в качестве индексов(df.index) по оси x и значения кросс-курса(df['Close']) по оси y.
Для рисования используется matplotlib.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = web.DataReader('USDCZK=X', 'yahoo', start='2015-05-15', end='2022-05-01')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, подключил это к кнопкам, все работает)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример построения графиков по точкам с `plt.plot`.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [9, 4, 2, 4, 9]
y2 = [1, 7, 6, 3, 5]
fg = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3), constrained_layout=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=1, figure=fg)
fig_ax_1 = fg.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
plt.plot(x, y1)
fig_ax_2 = fg.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
plt.plot(x, y2)
```

Сами графики и пример - на https://devpractice.ru/matplotlib-lesson-3-2-plot-layout/

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу (как второй ответ тут) - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).